# Facebook Comment showing less comment in Public View than in moderator view

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-social-plugins, facebook-comments

I have implemented a Facebook Comment plugin in a page tab. I am not able to see several comments in it. Till yesterday there were 88 comment now suddenly there are only 39 comments. If I check moderator view I can see more than 100 comments but in public view cannot see comments more than half of the comments. I have kept all comments to be public by default. I tried to figure out various reason that could be behind it but I still have no success. I have on e suspicion that someone has deliberately marked many comments as spam and hence facebook is hiding it. Though I believe at least the admin should be able to see it.

The Comment plugin points to this url : http://rcomsocialapps.com/netconnect_journey/comment.html

Even at https://developers.facebook.com/tools/comments i can see 100+ comments in public View

But the page where I hosted the plugin I see only 39 Comments : https://rcomsocialapps.com/netconnect_journey/postlike.php

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: It shows 103 comments when I visit your page (the FB page tab app), and http://graph.facebook.com/comments/?ids=http://rcomsocialapps.com/netconnect_journey/comment.html&limit=1000 also delivers more than 100.

Comment: Yeah in between even I could see 100 comments but when i refresh it becomes 39. I have attached screenshot what I see now. Could it be bug from Facebook side? I don't know how I can explain this to my Client :/

Comment: I see currently 103 comments on the page, even when I reload it multiple times. A colleague’s account however, gets shown only 41. So it must have something to do with _who_ is watching the comments. And if that colleague logs out of his account, he can see all 103 as well.

Comment: Is it a normal phenomenon? Is Facebook trying to show comments that are more socially close to current logged in user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar to unresolved Facebook Bug reported here -> https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/503273333023849?browse=search_50b496567d5059328231776